# Hash table: why buckets?

Tags: hash, hashtable

As far as i know, the point of a hash function is to distribute the data out as evenly as possible, when you have a collision you have several choices:

1. Look for the next empty slot
2. Generate a different hash and try to stick it somewhere else
3. Put it in an overflow container (could be a list, another hash table or whatever)
4. Put it in the next free bucket slot

The last one bothers me because, if you're going to make a hash table with say 2 slots for each address, why not just make a twice bigger hash table?  That is unless the buckets are dynamically allocated. In my case, where the data of the table sits on a disk that would mean another disk access + managing the variable length data. It seems to me though that buckets are still the most favored option, why is that? What am I missing?

Comment: "It seems to me though that buckets are still the most favored option" why? The first option, which is called linear hashing, is the simpliest and (a bit surprisingly) still the most efficient in most cases.

Comment: How is "1. Look for the next empty slot" meant to differ from "4. Put it in the next free bucket slot"?  Is the terminology you're used to having a fixed number of "slots" per bucket?  They you say "2 slots for each *address*" - do you mean for each bucket?  "buckets are dynamically allocated" - are you again referencing "3." - as dynamic buckets sounds like they're lists/vectors to me.

Comment: Anyway, for disk tables, loading a disk area is costly so it's better to use any free bucket rather before resorting to looking in another disk area.  I don't recommend multiple "slots" per bucket - just try another bucket.  A good idea is to use a "displacement list" that jumps a number of buckets (perhaps wrapping for a few retries within the loaded disk area, then do a brute force search, then move to another disk area or rehashing).  Displacement lists should avoid runs whose sum repeats: e.g. 1 3 6 is ok (3-1 != 6-3, n*(3-1) != 6-1), 11 is then bad: 6-1 == 11-6, 13 ok....

Comment: @TonyD first comment: It differs because the in #4 you'd have multiple preallocated spaces for kvps per hash. Yes, Yes. No, I'm implying that the only way buckets make sense to me is if they were dynamically allocated for memory savings, yes.
second comment: Yea that pretty much puts an end to #2. And yes that sounds like a great idea.

Comment: @KarliRaudsepp: the idea of multiple preallocated spaces per hash value is not useful... given the extra memory use, you're better off having the hashes splay out over all the available memory so there are less collisions to begin with, then handling collisions using any of the chaining / rehashing / displacement list techniques discussed.

Answer (score 6):

As is probably evident from the discussion in the comments on this question, there are many different ways that you can implement a hash table. Each has its own tradeoffs.

Your question is why you would want to use a bucketing system (closed addressing, or hashing with chaining) versus just dropping the object into the next free slot (linear probing). You point out that having buckets stored in external memory requires a lookup in another spot in memory, which isn't a good idea if you're storing things on disk. These are all valid concerns. However, here are a few things to keep in mind.

First, if you're using a bucketing system (each hash table slot is a bucket, and all objects with the same hash code get thrown into the same bucket), you have one advantage over systems like linear probing that use open addressing: the only collisions you have to worry about are for objects with identical hash codes. As an example, suppose that you insert three elements into a hash table and their hash codes are 1, 1, and 2. In closed addressing (buckets), whenever you perform a lookup for 1, you'll have to check both objects with hash code 1, but if you look up object 2 you don't have to do any collision resolution at all. On the other hand, if you use linear probing, you can have collisions when looking up any of the three elements. Let's say that object A has hash code 1, object B has hash code 2, and object C also has hash code 1. Inserting the objects in the order A, C, B would give this table:

```
[ A ] [ C ] [ B ] [   ] [   ]
  1     2     3
```

Now, performing a lookup for either C or B will require you to do a linear scan over the table, even though B doesn't collide with objects A or C. Depending on your application, this could be a real problem.

On the other hand, if you use bucketing, as you've mentioned, you need to do some sort of external memory access, which will be somewhat slow in main memory (due to locality of reference) and glacial on disk. That's a pretty good argument explaining why hashing with chaining would not be a good idea for an on-disk hash table, while linear probing would probably be a reasonable compromise.

Hope this helps!